# Eclipse for C/C++ Developers: Auto Build

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse for Java Developers, the whole project is built in the background every time any file is saved, which I find very convenient when compared to other IDEs.

Is there an equivalent in Eclipse for C/C++ developers? I seem to have to keep typing Ctrl+B to see most errors that are not syntax-related.

As you can see, I have all the correct settings, I guess "automatically" means something different to in the Java IDE:

[image: Preferences]

There are no questions that ask exactly the same thing on this site. Just to be specific, this is automatic building on save, not automatic saving on build.

Comment: What is the difference in behavior, if you uncheck "Build automatically"? -- TBH, I never build automatically after saving in C/C++ projects, because it takes longer than is convenient. Especially "normal" sized C++ projects with templates or even STL take a long time.

Comment: That *probably* shouldn't be the case unless you are putting a lot into a single file - is the compiler not doing any caching? I guess that might not be possible like it is in Java.

Comment: Well, unfortunately there seems to be no C or C++ compiler that is able to compile incrementally or to cache. Standard protocols to integrate such in IDEs don't exist, AFAIK. Clang as an infrastructure might be a candidate, however. -- And if I talk about "long time", I mean multiple hours for a professional grade C++ project using the Qt library. C applications are done much faster, commonly compiled in seconds. -- Anyway, if Eclipse offers automatic builds after saves, it should work somehow. I'm looking forward to the answer. ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm just writing a few basic C programs at the moment, so it could be quite handy (I'm currently stuck trying to debug a mysterious error with initialising a struct). When I type `ninja` to build, it seems to only compile files that have changed.

Comment: https://youtu.be/uKIuZpqROBk

Comment: Well, this is one important feature of builds controlled by Make or similar tools: compile only changed sources, and link only if an input module changed. :-) Didn't you expect this? You might want to read Make's documentation.

Comment: Isn't that incremental build? If so, then it is possible for large projects to compile in less than a second, unless you have really long files (which I don't).

Comment: Yes, it is incremental in the sense that only complete translation units are compiled. You cannot compile incrementally _parts_ of a compilation unit, as Java compilers (seem to) do. Anyway, the linking stage always includes _all_ modules. Java does not have such a linking stage, AFAIK, the class loader / JRE does this JIT during runtime. -- The reason behind this "incremental" approach in C comes from its early days, when RAM and compiler speed was very limited. Think about 16KB RAM and 1 MIPS... Today the complexity of C++ makes compilers really slow, but C is commonly fast.

Comment: I don't know how big people usually make compilation units, but I wouldn't expect it to take hours for a single file to compile. I thought Java always compiles the whole file, but I may be wrong. But this doesn't really matter; I just want to know if such an option exists.

Comment: The Java compiler javac does this, sure. But Eclipse's built-in compiler might compile each class separately, or even each method. I don't know. -- Anyway, we are distracted a lot. Unfortunately I don't have the chance to check Eclipse's capabilities ATM.